# Add new object to sub of sub array based on query in MongoDB using mongotemplate

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

Here is an existing document:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("58bfe67c71043e8947d487c7"),
    "_class": "com.plash.configurator.model.GmailMailData",
    "useremail": "xyx@gmail.com",
    "threadidslist": [
     {
       "threadid": "15aac9952c924e6c",
       "subject": "dd",
       "messagelist": [
         {
           "messageid": "15aad9c4ebba913c",
           "timestamp": "Wed Mar 08 11:09:45 UTC 2017",
           "from": "utsavanand.work@gmail.com",
           "body": "<div dir=\"ltr\">ddd</div>\r\n",
           "labelid": "RECEIVED"
         }
       ]
     }
    ]
}
```

The query I am using is:

```
Update update = new Update();
update.addToSet("messagelist", gm); //gm is the object of messaglist
Criteria criteria =  Criteria.where("useremail").is(useremailid)
                             .and("threadidslist.threadid").is(threadid);
mongoTemplate.updateFirst(Query.query(criteria), update, GmailMailData.class);
```

This query inserts the object at the top level, but I want the object to be added inside messagelist.

How do I add a new object inside messagelist if **useremail** and **threadid** matches?

Comment: Can you try `update.addToSet("threadidslist.$.messagelist", gm)` ?

Comment: @veeram Yup,tried it now,but no luck.

Comment: Thanks @Veeram  ,My criteria was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This query works:

```
 Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("useremail").is(useremailid).and("threadidslist.threadid").is(threadid));
            update.push("threadidslist.$.messagelist", gm);
            mongoTemplate.updateFirst(query, update, GmailMailData.class);
```